# Get file path from explorer search in excel

Tags: excel, vba, explorer

I am very new to using macros so am looking for solutions online.
What I want to do is exactly the same as has been asked in another question ([Extract file names from a File Explorer search into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63372774/extract-file-names-from-a-file-explorer-search-into-excel)) however I cannot get the proposed solution to work (honestly, I am too unexperienced to understand it).

I want to be able to search for files in a given location for a keyword within the **content of the files, not the filename**, and be able to get a list of file paths into excel for the files that are found through the search.

I was able to find a code that does the first part, i.e. opening windows explorer in a specific folder and finding the file(s) for a specific keyword.

```
Sub Search_files ()

dim eSearch As String
eSearch = "explorer " & Chr$(34) & "search-ms://query=System.Generic.String:" & [search term here] & "&crumb=location:" & [Directory Here] & Chr$(34)
Call Shell (eSearch)
    
End Sub
```

Next I would need to get the path of the files that turned up in the search into excel.
The solution proposed in the previous question says "Assuming the location is indexed you can access the catalog directly with ADO (add a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x)" and proposed the following:

```
Dim cn  As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs  As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String

cn.Open "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows'"

sql = "SELECT System.ItemNameDisplay, System.ItemPathDisplay FROM SystemIndex WHERE SCOPE='file:C:\look\here' AND System.Kind <> 'folder' AND CONTAINS(System.FileName, '""*.PDF""') AND CONTAINS ('""find this text""')"

rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

If Not rs.EOF Then
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print "File: "; rs.Collect(0)
        Debug.Print "Path: "; rs.Collect(1)
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

I added a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x and replaced `'file:C:\look\here'` with `'file:{myPath}'` and `('""find this text""')"`  with `('""{myText}""')"` . I do not get errors, it just doesn't do anything. I specify the files I have in the test folder are pdfs (since this code only looks for pdf files).

The author commented "I had to add: set cn = NEW ADODB.Connection set rs = NEW ADODB.Recordset before using any of the commands and then it worked perfectly." I did that as well but I can't get it to work.

Thanks to anyone who can suggest a solution/explain how the above works!

Comment: Try this out maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61191877/478884  (the ADO-based approach)

Comment: Hi Tim! I had seen that post but until this morning wasn't able to figure out what it was doing exactly (as said am very new to all this...) - but it works! I can see the information I want in the immediate window. I added a line to be able to get the information into a sheet: `Sheets("Log").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rs(0)`
 thanks a lot!